# Turbo C gives a totally different output than GCC, although the same code

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

So, here I wanted to add 2 polynomials using a linked-list in C. It gave a perfect output when compiled with GCC, but when compiled with TurboC++, it messed up...

The output it gave in GCC was:

```
Polynomial 1:   6x^3 + 10x^2 + 0x + 5 
Polynomial 2:   4x^2 + 2x + 1 
Added Polynomial :      6x^3 + 14x^2 + 2x + 6
```

The Output it  gave in TurboC++:

```
Polynomial 1:   6x^3 + <br>
Polynomial 2:   4x^2  <br>
Added Polynomial : 6x^3 + 4x
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int coeff;
    int power;
    struct node *next;
};

void display_poly(struct node *exp);
void addnode(int coeff, int power, struct node **prev_node);
void addpoly(struct node *poly1, struct node *poly2, struct node *result);

void main() {

    struct node *poly1 = NULL, *poly2 = NULL, *result = NULL;

    addnode(6, 3, &poly1);
    addnode(10, 2, &poly1);
    addnode(0, 1, &poly1);
    addnode(5, 0, &poly1);

    printf("\nPolynomial 1:\t");
    display_poly(poly1);
    
    addnode(4, 2, &poly2);
    addnode(2, 1, &poly2);
    addnode(1, 0, &poly2);

    printf("\nPolynomial 2:\t");
    display_poly(poly2);
    
    result = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    addpoly(poly1, poly2, result);

    printf("\nAdded Polynomial :\t");
    display_poly(result);
    
    return;
}

void addnode(int coeff, int power, struct node **prev_node) {    

    struct node *node1, *node2;

    node2 = *prev_node;
    if (node2 == NULL) {
        node1 = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        node1->coeff = coeff;
        node1->power = power;
        *prev_node = node1;
        node1->next = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        node1 = node1->next;
        node1->next = NULL;
    } else {
        node1->coeff = coeff;
        node1->power = power;
        node1->next = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        node1 = node1->next;
        node1->next = NULL;
    }
    return;
}

void display_poly(struct node *exp) {
    while (exp->next) {
        
        if (exp->power == 0) {
            printf("%d", exp->coeff);
        } else if (exp->power == 1) {
            printf("%dx", exp->coeff);
        } else {
            printf("%dx^%d", exp->coeff, exp->power);
        }
        
        exp = exp->next;
        
        if (exp->coeff >= 0 && exp->next != NULL) {
            printf(" + ");
        } else {
            printf("  ");
        }
    }
    return;   
}

void addpoly(struct node *poly1, struct node *poly2, struct node *result){

    while (poly1->next && poly2->next) {
        
        if (poly1->power > poly2->power) {
            result->power = poly1->power;
            result->coeff = poly1->coeff;
            poly1 = poly1->next; 
        } else if (poly2->power > poly1->power) {
            result->power = poly2->power;
            result->coeff = poly2->coeff;
            poly2 = poly2->next;
        } else {
            result->power = poly1->power;
            result->coeff = poly1->coeff + poly2->coeff;
            poly1 = poly1->next;
            poly2 = poly2->next;
        }

        result->next = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        result = result->next;
        result->next = NULL;
    }

    while (poly1->next || poly2->next) {
        if (poly1->next) {
            result->power = poly1->power;
            result->coeff = poly1->coeff;
            poly1 = poly1->next;
        }
        if (poly2->next) {
            result->power = poly2->power;
            result->coeff = poly2->coeff;
            poly2 = poly2 -> next;
        }
        result->next = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        result = result->next;
        result->next = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: C is not C++, don't tag bog languages. And Turbo C is older than the first C standard (C89) so don't expect language-compliant results in it

Comment: Once I removed `conio.h`, changed `void main` to `int main`, and `return` to `return 0` this compiles with g++. It also provides helpful information about errors in the code. https://godbolt.org/z/cn14hbrPj

Comment: In `display_poly`, the line `while (exp -> next)` looks wrong.  Typically you want the simpler `while (exp)` in a loop like that.

Comment: Seriously.  I saw "Turbo C" and I wondered if Doc and Marty were here

Comment: Are you using C or C++?

Answer (score 1):

Your code has undefined behaviour:

```
void addnode(int coeff, int power, struct node** prev_node) 
{    
  struct node* node1, * node2;  // <<< node1 is not initialized

  node2 = *prev_node;
  if (node2 == NULL) {
    node1 = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    node1->coeff = coeff;
    node1->power = power;
    *prev_node = node1;
    node1->next = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    node1 = node1->next;
    node1->next = NULL;    
  }
  else {
    node1->coeff = coeff;  // <<<< here node1 is not initialized
    node1->power = power;
    node1->next = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    node1 = node1->next;
    node1->next = NULL;
  }
  return;
}
```

`node1` has not been initialized (see comment in the code above), and dereferencing an uninitialized pointer is *undefined behaviour* (google that term). Change `struct node* node1` to `struct node* node1 = NULL` and run the program again. This time you'll most likely get a segfault with gcc. With Turbo C I don't know what is going to happen.

You probably want this:

```
void addnode(int coeff, int power, struct node** prev_node) {

  struct node* node1 = NULL , *node2;

  node2 = *prev_node;
  node1 = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  node1->coeff = coeff;
  node1->power = power;
  node1->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

  if (node2 == NULL) {
    *prev_node = node1;
    node1 = node1->next;
    node1->next = NULL;

  }
  else {
    node1 = node1->next;
    node1->next = NULL;
  }
  return;
}
```

BTW: the `(struct node*)` of `malloc` are useless, you can simply drop them.

That being said, don't use Turbo C, this is an antiquated piece of software that is most likely older than you.

There may be other problems in your code though.

Comment: Why should `add_node` allocate 2 nodes?

Comment: @chqrlie I have no idea, maybe the original program logic is flawed already.

Comment: I don't use TurboC++, I don't even like it... But my college exams will be held in turbo C++.... :'(

Comment: @PratikChoudhuri I'm really wondering why colleges still use TurboC nowadays.